# Proof of Matrix Symmetry

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Here's my proof for the following:
Given A,P $\in Mn(R)$, show that
A symmetric $=> B=P^TAP $ symmetric

A symmetric $=> A=A^T$ symmetric

$B=P^TAP$

$(P^TAP)=P^TAP$

$(P^TAP)=(P^TAP)^T$

$(P^TAP)=P^{TT}A^TP^T$

$(P^TAP)=PA^TP^T$

Recall $A=A^T$

$(P^TAP)=PAP^T$

is there something I missed or is there a more thorough proof?

Comment: $(P^TAP)=(P^TAP)^T$ => following transpose property $(P^TAP)=P^TA^TP^{TT}$ => recall $A=A^T$  $(P^TAP)=P^TAP$

Comment: How do you know that $P^TAP=(P^TAP)^T$? It is more or less what you need to prove. In addition, it is not clear where the statement $B^T=B$ (what you actually want to prove) is hidden. Why don't you go simply with $B^T=(P^TAP)^T=P^TA^T(P^T)^T=P^TAP=B$?

Comment: Well if A is symmetric then B must be symmetric, so I assume that the transpose of B is equal to B. Thus I then try to prove that B is equal to its transpose which it is. And according to the transpose property don't you write the elements you are transposing in the opposite order after you do the transpose?..That is why I did in my first comment.